# Need direct url/access to images for newsletter

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter, access

I am facing one problem in my magento website.

I have a email newsletter which have some images to show.

My problem is to access the images outside the website. For example, when i typed the url/path of images paced in website, it shows 404 error, because magento think this is a some page name(which is not actually).

I just want to access those images. For example example.com/newsletter_images/offer.jpg

Guys, please help. I am stucked in this.

Thanks in advance

-Amrinder

Comment: If you put an image in a folder outside of the Magento install you should be able to access that image you described since you are not even loading Magento. Are you sure you don't have an htaccess file in your folder or a rule that will not allow you to browse that folder?

Comment: Hello Brentwpeterson,

Thankyou for replying me.

My folder/image location is already outside the Magento direcptory.
My folder is at public_html/newsletter_images

All other folders like app, downloader, errors, includes, js, lib, shell, skin etc are also in "public_html"

I am still not able to access the image at location public_html/newsletter_images/offer.jpg with direct type of name like example.com/newsletter_images/offer.jpg

Thankyou in advance
-Amrinder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento makes sure, that it only rewrites files that don't exist and if they are outside `media` `skin` and `js`:

```
.htaccess
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

So what you describe shouldn't happen.

Did you put the file inside your root directory inside `/newsletter_images/` and name it `offer.jpg`

Comment: Hello Fabian Blechschmidt,

Thankyou for replying me.

My folder/image location is already outside the Magento direcptory.
My folder is at public_html/newsletter_images

All other folders like app, downloader, errors, includes, js, lib, shell, skin etc are also in "public_html"

I am still not able to access the image at location public_html/newsletter_images/offer.jpg with direct type of name like example.com/newsletter_images/offer.jpg

Thankyou in advance
-Amrinder

Comment: Then something is "wrong" with your htaccess or apache configuration. turn on high logging for apache, so you can see what rewrites are done.

Comment: Okay, so can you please tell me how can I turn on High Logging ?

Comment: I would try this: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging And check the access_log whether you request the right file

Comment: That sub domain required htaccess file. Now issue has been resolved. Thanks Fabian.

Comment: Please post the answer or mark mine as answer.

Comment: Hey Fabian, you did this. Thanks for your help.